# SET Parameter DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, parameters

I need set the parameter date for compare on a SQL Server table.

Where the day, month and year he will add the QUANTIDADE and weight of fish.

But giving this a mistake and falling in the catch and can not set it.

`DATA_REGISTRO` is a `Date` datatype in SQL Server.

Code:

```
 public void Search_DATE(string param_date)
 {
        SqlDataReader objReader;
        SqlCommand objcmd = null;

        vsql = "SELECT [IDCADASTRO],[RGP],[PEIXE],[PESO],[QUANTIDADE],[DATA_REGISTRO] FROM cadastro WHERE DATA_REGISTRO LIKE @DATA_REGISTRO";

        if (this.Conectar())
        {
            try
            {
                objcmd = new SqlCommand(vsql, objCon);
                objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", param_date));
                objReader = objcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (objReader.Read())
                {
                    valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetDateTime(5).ToString;

                }

            }
            catch (SqlException erro)
            {
                throw erro;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Desconectar();
            }
}
```

Global Variable

```
private static string date_time;

public string retorna_date_time
{
    get { return date_time; }
    set { date_time = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> DATA_REGISTRO is a Date type on SQL

However, you are supplying a string parameter

```
public string retorna_date_time
objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", param_date));
```

Instead, supply a DateTime parameter

```
DateTime dtParam = DateTime.Parse(param_date);
objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", dtParam));
```

Also, it is not a good idea to catch an exception unless you will do something with it

```
catch (SqlException erro)
{
    throw erro;
}
```

I understand you may have that line in there for debugging, but remove it from your final code unless there is something you can do with the exception.

Comment: Hum ok.More the ID on valor.retorna_date_time = objReader.GetDateTime(5).ToString; is 5 correct ?

Comment: GetDateTime(5) returns the column QUANTIDADE because that is the 5th column in your query.  It's safer to use `objReader.GetDateTime(objReader.GetOrdinal("QUANTIDADE")).ToString()` because it will figure out which column number QUANTIDATE is at runtime.  If you add or remove columns from your query, nothing will break.

Comment: Hello again I tried the way you recommended.The error: FormatException was unhandled.
When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take de date before putting each variable into de DateTime Object. I need get Date string of SQL to compare with other DateTime string.

Comment: FormatException means that whatever is in the string cannot be interpreted as a DateTime using your locale settings.  What exactly is in the string?

Comment: That part I already packed. Now I did in the example you gave me only the valor.retorna_date_time this returning me " " you can tell me why?

Comment: Step through in the debugger.  Does it go to the line that assigns a value there?  Possibly your query is not returning any rows.

Comment: I registered in SQL five values equal DATE. But is returning me " ". What can I do to fix?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Date` of you `param_date`.

```
objcmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DATA_REGISTRO", Convert.ToDateTime(param_date).Date));
```